# outOfMemory in for loop java

Tags: java, loops, out-of-memory

I am iterating 500,000 items using for loop , after 300, 000 item i am getting Out of memory , I have also tried to split loop in 100,000 still, but that also didn't work. When I increased memory in runConfig-xms10g, its working fine. Can anyone tell me how to split and free memory or any other way to iterate large number of recods.

```
protected Map<Long, Map<String, String>> getExistingItems()
{

  Map<Long, Map<String, String>> items = new HashMap<Long, Map<String, String>>();
  for (Item item : itemMaster.getItems()) {
     if (item.getExpirationDate() == null && !items.containsValue(item.getItemId())) {
        Map<String, String> item_hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (item.getEffectiveDate() != null)
           item_hash.put("effectiveDate", sdf.format(item.getEffectiveDate().getTime()));
        for (ItemMasterAttributeValue attrVal : item.getItemMasterAttributeValues()) {
           item_hash.put(attrVal.getId().getItemMasterAttribute().getCode(), attrVal.getValue());
        }
        items.put(item.getItemId(), item_hash);
     }
  }
```

after splitting below is code:

```
protected Map<Long, Map<String, String>> getExistingItems()
{

  Map<Long, Map<String, String>> items = new HashMap<Long, Map<String, String>>();
  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
  System.out.println("before getItems : " + new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
  Collection<Item> allItems = itemMaster.getItems();
  System.out.println("after getItems : " + new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
  int split = (allItems.size() / 100000);
  Map<Integer, Collection<Item>> splitMap = new HashMap<Integer, Collection<Item>>();
  Collection<Item> tempCollection = new ArrayList<Item>();
  int splitKey = 1;
  int key = 1;
  for(Item item : allItems)
  {
     tempCollection.add(item);
     if(splitKey / 100000 >= key && splitKey % 100000 == 0)
     {
        splitMap.put(key, tempCollection);
        tempCollection = new ArrayList<Item>();
        key++;
     }
     splitKey++;
  }
  splitMap.put(key, tempCollection);

  System.out.println("map size " + splitMap.size());
  for(int i = 1; i <= split + 1; i++)
  {
     System.out.println("i is :" + i + " " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
     for(Item item : splitMap.get(i))
  {
     if(!items.containsKey(item.getItemId()))
     {
        Map<String, String> item_hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (item.getEffectiveDate() != null)
           item_hash.put("effectiveDate", sdf.format(item.getEffectiveDate().getTime()));
        for (ItemMasterAttributeValue attrVal : item.getItemMasterAttributeValues()) {
           item_hash.put(attrVal.getId().getItemMasterAttribute().getCode(), attrVal.getValue());
        }
        items.put(item.getItemId(), item_hash);
     }
     }
     System.gc();
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you divide it into batches. The memory will still overflow as the size of your `tempCollection` grows. Change your code in a way that it keeps removing the items from `allItems` as you grow your `tempCollection`.

Comment: What are your JVM memory settings?  Why are you doing this?  If your data is coming from a database, then you should do the heavy lifting there.  If you cannot increase your Java heap size, then maybe you can write out to disk.

Comment: You don't seem to be creating any copies except for `sdf.format`. Unless that creates a huge `String` the memory requirement seems to come from the size of `itemMaster` itself. It maybe worth checking what is the memory usage at the start of the method, there is probably not a whole lot left

Comment: thanks everyone, I need to think to modify the whole method